# SignalR: no messaging until file uploaded/downloaded at the same web site

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have some problem when proceed downloading or uploading file (WebClient.DownloadFileAsync|UploadFileAsync or by HttpWebRequest) and simultaneously calling SignalR-hub methods:

SignalR calls were stopped until file loading finished.
It seems like that: all signalr calls enqueuing. All enqueued calls are performed further (after file loading).

My code fragment:

```
hubProxy.Invoke("TraceDocumentUploadingRequest", callerId, fileName, "File loading started ", 0);

DownloadFileByKey(fileKey, (progressPercentage, bytesSent) => { hubProxy.Invoke("TraceDocumentUploadingRequest", callerId, fileName, "File loading in progress", progressPercentage); });

hubProxy.Invoke("TraceDocumentUploadingRequest", callerId, fileName, "File loading finished", 100);
```

Second "TraceDocumentUploadingRequest" hub method call (in file load handler) will be executed on the hub after file downloading completion.

File load handler executes both in current thread or in another (related on DownloadFileByKey method realization) - result is the same.

How I can avoid this behavior and force hub-method calls at the right time?

Comment: What version of SignalR are you using?

Comment: All components are of 1.1.3 version

Comment: This is something we've fixed in later versions of SignalR. As a workaround, you can try upping the number of concurrent connections in service point manager to something like 100: ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx

Comment: David, You mean 2.0.0-rc1 version?

Comment: Yes 2.0.0-rc1 and the upcoming 2.0 release.

Comment: David, thank you for the help! It's working ar 2.0.0-rc1

Answer (score 0):

To summarize David Fowl's comments, the issue was a bug in SignalR version 1.1.3 but fixed in later version. Specifically version [2.0.0](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/releases/tag/2.0.0)